# Is there any SO-like site where I can discuss questions about graphic design?

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-recommendation, design

I'm not sure that it's the right place for this question but I don't know a better one.

So, I'd like to ask some questions about graphic design but I cannot find anything appropriate. Is there anything design-related on Area51 or anywhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Sure!

http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

There is a proposal on Area51, [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design?referrer=h9QT4T6CXHc1) - it looks like it needs a few more interested users, but you could add your name ;p

If that isn't quite what you are after, perhaps [search](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=search) for a more appropriate site. There is also [doctype](http://doctype.com/) that may help.

Comment: Yes, that proposal is really what I need. Maybe, it would help me next time. Commited.

Comment: BTW, I'm pretty sure it's potentially very popular site, but designers simply don't know about it. If it was possible to make a relevant post on, for example, smashingmagazine.com then this proposal would be in beta in 2 hours:)

Comment: I'll flag that upwards, but also: please feel free to spread the word! You show see a "Share This" link (that also helps track that *you've* been spreading the word)

Comment: so, is it ok to use Area 51 referral links without Disclaimer?

Comment: @Tobias - what disclaimer would you like to add? Maybe I've missed something, but based on "Tell your friends!
A good Q&A site needs lots of people! Use this custom URL to invite anyone who might be interested:", I *assume* that is fine...

Comment: Yeah, I just thought unindicated referral links to *other* sites were frowned upon, so I added a "Disclaimer: referral link" to the link's alt text. But if you say so, I'll skip that from now on

Comment: @Tobias - I see what you mean; but - all you get is a badge... it isn't like an affiliation/payment/ad-sales thing...

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I've sent some info to smashingmagazine, will wait. BTW, is there a possibility to get a 'clean` link, without my ID? I think, those link would have more changes to be published in a public place.

Comment: @Roman - sure, just take off the `?referrer=` so you have `http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design` - have I misunderstood?

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I confused myself. I thought that url part `1924` somehow refers to me. So, I gave a clear link as I wanted. I have doubts that they react on it but lets hope)

Answer (score 1):

Only similar thing I've seen is: http://doctype.com/questions